# Search for all git commits (on all branches) that contain a specified file?

Tags: git

I am trying to list all git commits on all branches on which a specific file exist. I know the full path to the file. I am not trying to search for commits that mention the file in their commit message, but rather commits that contain the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
git rev-list --all | xargs -I COMMIT \
    bash -c 'git cat-file -e COMMIT:myfile.py 2> /dev/null && echo COMMIT'
```

Comment: @jeremytwfortune That assumes that the file is present in the current commit. My goal was to find a file that I had lost but which I knew existed in some commit.

Comment: To do that, you just need to include `--` to separate the path. `git --all --format="%H" -- pathspec`. You mentioned that you knew the path of the file, so this will work (I just tried it with a file no longer in the current commit or anywhere in `HEAD`).